# ASP.NET MVC Web Config Email Settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, web-config

I'm trying to include some SMTP settings in my ASP.NET MVC project by adding the following to my Web.Config file:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network
             host="host"
             port="25"
             userName="username"
             password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This usually works for me in a standard ASP.NET application however in MVC, it's causing my site to render as blank (no source code in the browser atall).

My application builds ok so I assume I'm just missing a key piece in the MVC model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the answer is to include the settings inside of the `<configSections>`, after the `<sectionGroup>` section.

Putting the code before the `<sectionGroup>` tagset seems to result in the blank result I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error when I put this in the `<ConfigSections>` group, however it worked when I put it immedietly after `</ConfigSections>`.  Are you sure you didn't put it outside the `<configSections>`?